# How to see the filenames imported by the Feeds module?

Tags: feeds

Is there any way to see the past filenames that have been imported by the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module (using Drupal 7)?

I am trying to warn people if they try to import a file that has already been uploaded by Feeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this patch and it saves the filenames in the log now https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/1045818-feeds_log_filename.patch

Answer (score 1):

Imported files are stored in `default/files/feeds` by default I think so you could test on that first.

Feeds does create a watchdog event but it doesn't persist.

If you attach feeds to a node then you have several advantages. You can re run the import. And more interestingly you can access the node via Views and probably Rules. With those two you could build something with a Rules trigger event on the node save or Feeds import that would check for an existing node with a matching file.

If you can't get that working then post back and I'll try to make an example.

Comment: How would you attach a feed to a node?

Comment: Feed > Basic settings > Attach to content type. I recommend that you first create a special content type just for this purpose. Then, when a user needs to import something, they should be directed to the node add for that content type.